# Use setTimeout to restore variable values from when setTimeout is created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, settimeout, dom-events

Edit: I ultimately want to use setTimeout to restore a previous value of a variable at a later time

I created the following example to illustrate my point: ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marsguy/dwzxjco6/3/))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Push the button</p>
<button id = "push">Try it</button>

<script>
var x = {};
x.boo = "foo";
function myFunction() {
    alert(x.boo);
}
document.getElementById('push').addEventListener('click',function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myFunction(x)
    }, 1000);

    x.boo = 'baz'; //eg. something else modifies x before first timer runs out
    // another timer gets created, should reflect new value in x
    // added delay is just to keep track of the order myFunction is being executed
    setTimeout(function() {
        myFunction(x)
    }, 3000);
},false‌​);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### What happens:

After clicking button, alert() window shows 'baz' after 1 second, then 'baz' after 3 seconds.

### What I want to happen:

After clicking button, alert window should show 'foo', then after 3 seconds show 'baz'.

I've tried wrapping the myFunction callback in another anonymous function sent to setTimeout, as well as tried passing in params instead, both of which do not change behavior.

In my app, jQuery library is loaded so I also have that at my disposal if needed.

Comment: Hint: `setTimeout()` does *not* pause execution for the specified time, it schedules a function to be run later and then execution continues immediately at the instruction after `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I know; What I'm asking for is help on how I could capture the existing value at the time setTimeout is called.

Comment: Tip: don't put any code in your HTML. Bind handlers to HTML elements from JavaScript. Bad: `<button onclick="…">`. Good: `<button id="foo"> ... <script>document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click',myFunction,false);`

Comment: I did that in the jsFiddle; it was only done here to be concise.

Comment: Why not store it in a different variable? Why are you trying to achieve this? It seems like there is a reason you aren't explaining and it is possible there is a better way to achieve what you want if we knew the real reason behind this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var x = {};
x.boo = "foo";
function myFunction(x2) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(x2));
}
$('#push').on('click', function() {
    // Deep copy
    var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, x);
    setTimeout(function() { myFunction(newObject); }, 1000);
    x.boo='baz';
    setTimeout(function() { myFunction(x); }, 3000);
});
```

Updated fiddle with this approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/vijayP/dwzxjco6/7/

Comment: That would work, except x.boo='baz' represents another button changing the value of x before the timeout is called. See updated question.

Comment: @Aaron_H - check this.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up with something similar to this - I created a closure to copy the object and then set the timeout

Comment: Thanks @Aaron_H...`:)`!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know wheather this what you want it or just have a look to it.First on Click it will show an alert foo and then after 3sec's it will show baz alert.have a look at this code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <p>Push the button</p>
<button onclick="myFunction();x.boo='baz';setTimeout(myFunction, 3000,x);">Try it</button>

  <script>
  var x = {};
  x.boo = "foo";
  function myFunction() {
  alert(x.boo);
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are going in infinite loop... `:)`! please update you answer.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Push the button</p>
<button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);">Try it</button>

<script>
var x = {};
x.boo = "foo";
function myFunction() {
    alert(x.boo);
    x.boo = "baz";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should have clarified, x.boo='baz' represents, for example, another button changing the value of x before the timeout ends. See updated question.